# How can I refer to this metaclass inside a metaclass without specifying its name in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass

I have some python code:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, attrs):
        attrs.update({'name': '', 'email': ''})
        return super().__new__(cls, name, base, attrs)

    def __init__(cls, name, base, attrs):
        super().__init__(name, base, attrs)
        cls.__init__ = Meta.func

    def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        setattr(self, 'LOCAL', True)


class Man(metaclass=Meta):
    login = 'user'
    psw = '12345'
```

How can I refer to this metaclass inside a metaclass without specifying its name in the code? Without `Meta` in the row: `cls.__init__ = Meta.func`

If someone wants to change the name of the metaclass, it will stop working. Because it will be necessary to make changes inside this metaclass. Because I explicitly specified its name in the code. I think this is not right. But I do not know how to express it in another way.

I tried `cls.__init__ = cls.func`, but it doesn't create local variables for the Man class object. `cls` refers to the class being created(`Man`), not the `Meta`

Comment: The official Python documentation details [how to write and use classes](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Done. But there is no answer to my question there

Comment: Please describe what you expect this to do. What does "OOP true" mean?

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. You need to explain what you think is wrong with the above code.

Comment: Good. If I want to change the name of the metaclass, it will stop working. Because it will be necessary to make changes inside this metaclass. Because I explicitly specified his name in the code. I think it won't be right.

Comment: Why did you choose to write a metaclass rather than inheriting from a parent that provides the intended `__init__` method?

Comment: I'm learning how to use metaclasses correctly. I understand that it is easier to apply inheritance. In this example, I'm using a metaclass to create new classes. The new class will not necessarily be Man. I can do it like this:
`Woman = Meta('Woman', (), '{'name': 'Jane'})`
And I'll get a new class 'Woman'. And if an instance of this class is created, then I will already have __init__ registered for it.

Comment: For most people, using metaclasses correctly means *not using them*.

Comment: It's sad. Thank you for your answer anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I refer to this metaclass inside a metaclass without
> specifying its name in the code? Without Meta in the row: cls.**init**
> = Meta.func

You can use the special variable name `__class__`, like in:

```
cls.__init__ = __class__.__init__
```

Otherwise, the first "cls" parameter in the `__init__` method of the metaclass have a reference to the class'class (the metaclass), just as a regular `self` parameter would:

```
 cls.__init__ = cls.__class__.__init__
```

would also work for referencing the function.

Comment: I might use `type(self)` instead of `__class__` (which, I think, is more of an implementation detail for `super` than something to use explicitly).

Comment: @chepner nah, the attribute `__class__` isn't related to the special `__class__` variable for `super`, but I also prefer `type(x)` instead of `x.__class__`, but `.__class__` is a documented feature

Comment: Right, two different things named `__class__`...

Comment: I don't think my surprise on discovering about the stand-alone `__class__` has passed yet. And I learned about it more than 10 years ago.